# how can I convert model to entity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I can not save data in database beacuse model can not convert to entity,
I am getting data from model but Add function can not add intodatabase.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Patient Patient)
{
    _context.Patients.Add(Patient); "(Error here)"
    try
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Patients");
}
```

}

> Error :cannot convert from 'CandidateScreening.Models.Patient' to 'CandidateScreening.Data.Entities.Patient'

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different classes for viewmodel and data model, of course both of them cannot implicitly converted to each other. The simplest way to enable conversion is using [implicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) (or [explicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit), depending on context) to convert between viewmodel and data model, see this example below:

```
public static implicit operator Patient(PatientVM patient)
{
    return new Patient
    {
        // list of properties
        // example:
        // PatientId = patient.PatientId
    };
}
```

Then assign viewmodel contents to data model inside POST action method as provided below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PatientVM patient)
{
    Patient patientData = patient;

    _context.Patients.Add(patientData);

    // other stuff

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Patients");
}
```

**Note:** The viewmodel class name intentionally changed in the example to differentiate between data model & viewmodel class.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). Here is an example:

```
CandidateScreening.Data.Entities.Patient patient = Mapper.Map<CandidateScreening.Data.Entities.Patient>(patientVm);//where patientVm has type CandidateScreening.Models.Patient
```

Comment: Automapper will give you a much more maintenable solution indeed